# Unique words save to text file as a word per line

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, io, text-files

[using Python 3.3.3]

I'm trying to analyse text files, clean them up, print the amount of unique words, then try to save the unique words list to a text file, one word per line with the amount of times each unique word appears in the cleaned up list of words.
SO what i did was i took the text file (a speech from prime minister harper), cleaned it up by only counting valid alphabetical characters and single spaces, then i counted the amount of unique words, then i needed to make a saved text file of the unique words, with each unique word being on its own line and beside the word, the number of occurances of that word in the cleaned up list. Here's what i have.

```
def uniqueFrequency(newWords):
    '''Function returns a list of unique words with amount of occurances of that
word in the text file.'''
    unique = sorted(set(newWords.split()))
    for i in unique:
        unique = str(unique) + i + " " + str(newWords.count(i)) + "\n"
    return unique

def saveUniqueList(uniqueLines, filename):
    '''Function saves result of uniqueFrequency into a text file.'''
    outFile = open(filename, "w")
    outFile.write(uniqueLines)
    outFile.close
```

newWords is the cleaned up version of the text file, with only words and spaces, nothing else. So, I want each unique word in the newWords file to be saved to a text file, one word per line, and beside the word, have the # of occurances of that word in newWords (not in unique words list because then each word would have 1 occurance). What is wrong with my functions? Thank you!

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unique = str(unique) + i + " " + str(newWords.count(i)) + "\n"
```

The line above, is appending at the end of the existing set - "unique", if you use some other variable name instead, like "var", that should return correctly.

```
def uniqueFrequency(newWords):
    '''Function returns a list of unique words with amount of occurances of that
word in the text file.'''
    var = "";
    unique = sorted(set(newWords.split()))
    for i in unique:
        var = str(var) + i + " " + str(newWords.count(i)) + "\n"
    return var
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on

```
unique = sorted(set(newWords.split()))
for i in unique:
    unique = str(unique) + i + " " + str(newWords.count(i)) + "\n"
```

I am guessing that `newWords` is not a list of strings but a long string. If that's the case, `newWords.count(i)` will return `0` for every `i`.

Try:

```
def uniqueFrequency(newWords):
    '''Function returns a list of unique words with amount of occurances of that
word in the text file.'''
    wordList = newWords.split()
    unique = sorted(set(wordList))
    ret = ""
    for i in unique:
        ret = ret + i + " " + str(wordList.count(i)) + "\n"
    return ret
```

Comment: This answer is awesome as well. This got me the correct amount of occurances of the word, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `collections.Counter` instead. It is made for situations like this.

Demonstration in [IPython](http://ipython.org/) below:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: txt = """I'm trying to analyse text files, clean them up, print the amount of unique words, then try to save the unique words list to a text file, one word per line with the amount of times each unique word appears in the cleaned up list of words. SO what i did was i took the text file (a speech from prime minister harper), cleaned it up by only counting valid alphabetical characters and single spaces, then i counted the amount of unique words, then i needed to make a saved text file of the unique words, with each unique word being on its own line and beside the word, the number of occurances of that word in the cleaned up list. Here's what i have."""

In [3]: Counter(txt.split())
Out[3]: Counter({'the': 10, 'of': 7, 'unique': 6, 'i': 5, 'to': 4, 'text': 4, 'word': 4, 'then': 3, 'cleaned': 3, 'up': 3, 'amount': 3, 'words,': 3, 'a': 2, 'with': 2, 'file': 2, 'in': 2, 'line': 2, 'list': 2, 'and': 2, 'each': 2, 'what': 2, 'did': 1, 'took': 1, 'from': 1, 'words.': 1, '(a': 1, 'only': 1, 'harper),': 1, 'was': 1, 'analyse': 1, 'one': 1, 'number': 1, 'them': 1, 'appears': 1, 'it': 1, 'have.': 1, 'characters': 1, 'counted': 1, 'list.': 1, 'its': 1, "I'm": 1, 'own': 1, 'by': 1, 'save': 1, 'spaces,': 1, 'being': 1, 'clean': 1, 'occurances': 1, 'alphabetical': 1, 'files,': 1, 'counting': 1, 'needed': 1, 'that': 1, 'make': 1, "Here's": 1, 'times': 1, 'print': 1, 'up,': 1, 'beside': 1, 'trying': 1, 'on': 1, 'try': 1, 'valid': 1, 'per': 1, 'minister': 1, 'file,': 1, 'saved': 1, 'single': 1, 'words': 1, 'SO': 1, 'prime': 1, 'speech': 1, 'word,': 1})
```

(Note that this solution isn't perfect yet; it hasn't removed the commas from the words. hint; use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).)

The `Counter` is a specialized `dict`, with a word as the key, and the count as the value. So you can use it like this:

```
 cnts = Counter(txt)
 with open('counts.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     for c in counts:
         outfile.write("{} {}\n".format(c, cnts[c]))
```

Note that in this solution I used some nice-to-know Python concepts;

- a [context manager](http://eigenhombre.com/2013/04/20/introduction-to-context-managers/)
- iteration over a `dict` (which is an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterable#iterator-types))
- [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)